# How do I make spaces between paragraphs in my Python script?

Tags: python, paragraph

I'm making a game in Python (text only) but it gets confusing when people play it because there is no space between the paragraphs, so it looks like this:

```
'You step outside and feel the wind on your face.'
'Which direction do you turn?'
```

But I would like it to look like this:

```
'You step outside and feel the breeze on your face'

'What do you do next'?
```

Here's my code:

```
print 'You step outside and feel the cool breeze on your face.'
what = raw_input ('What do you do next ')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Print a newline character.

```
print("\n")
```

Or:

```
print("An angry-looking dwarf throws an axe at you.\nYou die.\n")
```

Comment: print("An angry-looking dwarf throws an axe at you.\n\nYou die.\n")        .     2 times '\n' will come

Answer (score 3):

You have a few solutions:

The simpler one would be to use a `print` statement between your lines, which, used alone, prints a line feed.

Alternatively, you could you end the string you're printing with a `'\n'` character, which will cause a line feed, or you could start your input with the same character.

Answer (score 1):

```
print('\v')
```

vertical tab for vertical space.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you three Solutions.

**First Solution**

```
  print(f"""You step outside and feel the breeze on your face


  What do you do next?""")
```

**Second Solution**

```
print("You step outside and feel the breeze on your face. \n\nWhat do you do next?")
```

**Third Solution**

```
print("You step outside and feel the breeze on your face")
print("\n")
print("What do you do next?")
```

Check Out the Image Given Below for Code and Output .

[image: Check Out the Image for code and output]